# How to get all the MIME types that File Info (Finfo) extention get detect?

Tags: php, types, mime

How to get all the MIME types that File Info (Finfo) extention can detect?
how to get his database / file?
I have Finfo on my wamp.
thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

When not magic file is specified at constructor time then FileInfo use the file specified in MAGIC environment variable

> Name of a magic database file, usually something like /path/to/magic.mime. If not specified, the MAGIC environment variable is used. If this variable is not set either, /usr/share/misc/magic is used by default. A .mime and/or .mgc suffix is added if needed.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-open.php

So `$magic = getenv('MAGIC');` is the way to get the database used by default

Comment: I'm israeli, can you explain the grammer fixing?

Answer (score 0):

(Wamp) It's in 
C:\wamp\bin\apache\apacheX.X.X\conf\mime.types